Is it unwise to extend (as in: put in non-column properties) the Entity classes of EF Core?
Let's say I have two classes representing two tables in the DB
public partial class TableA
{
  public int TableAId { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableB
{
  public int TableBId { get; set; }
}

and then in other files I'd have
public interface IId
{
  int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableA : IId
{
  int IId.Id { get => this.TableAId; set => this.TableAId = value; }
}

public partial class TableB : IId
{
  int IId.Id { get => this.TableBId; set => this.TableBId = value; }
}

I know that the classes are substituted with CastleProxy instances and such but I have no idea how exactly this would impact the behaviour of EF Core.
Note: underlying DB is SQL Server

No, Entities arent' tables and EF doesn't use CastleProxy. There's no base "Entity" class, any C# class can be used. Entity means an application entity, like Product or Customer, not a database table. The job of ORMs is to Map Objects to Relational storage, so you can take your Order object with its 5 Order.OrderItems, each with 1 OrderItem.Product and 1 Order.Customer and store the entire object graph in the database

There's no inheritance in the question either. There's no CorporateCustomer:Customer. IId is an implemented interface and frankly, not useful. Can EF map derived entities to tables? Yes it can, using various strategies. Does EF need and IId inteface? Not at all, in fact that's a smell. EF Core uses naming conventions for relation and key discovery so an Id or CustomerId column will be considered the PK of the Customer class automatically

Relation conventions mean you don't even have to provide foreign key properties. If you have a Post[] Blog.Posts property and a Blog Post.Blog, and the entity IDs follow conventions, EF will detect the relation automatically, create shadow properties for BlogId and map them to tables and columns with corresponding names

@PanagiotisKanavos for me an instantiated class is of type Castle.Proxies.TableAProxy
The IId (which is just a generic example by itself) is for other purposes in the code to make use of code reusabilty via interfaces and generic constraints

I know what such interfaces are used (or misused) for. They're an idea copied from Java long ago that didn't take into account the Lambdas and Expressions that allow eg LINQ to work without requiring any interfaces or proxies. It seems the real question isn't about inheritance (there's none in the question) but whether interfaces like IId make sense - it depends. Interfaces are hard-coded, expressions like those used by LINQ aren't , and they're still type safe. When used blindly, such interfaces are a bad idea. Sometimes they're a workaround for missing C# features like type inference.

So the answer to your question is "it depends on how they're used". And the question's code doesn't seem useful - why not use Id instead of CustomerId? You can easily map it to a different column name with an attribute. Calling entities tables on the other hand rings a dozen alarm bells.

@PanagiotisKanavos, EF Core uses CastleProxy for Lazy loading.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv you're right. I use lazy loading so rarely I forget this - frankly, I can't remember the last time I used lazy loading. There's little use for lazy loading in backend coding.

Its perfectly legal to use inheritance for entity classes,
when you use inherited entities the EF creates one more extra column in the SQL table. You can add the [NotMapped] data annotation to the property which is derived.
// @nuget: EntityFramework

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            context.Ingredients.Add(new Vegetable() { ID=1, Name ="Carrot"});
            context.Ingredients.Add(new Vegetable() { ID=2, Name ="Chilly"});           
            context.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient() { ID=3 });//Name ="Capscicum"
            
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            var list = context.Ingredients.ToList();
            
            FiddleHelper.WriteTable("Ingredients", list);           
        }
    }

    public class EntityContext : DbContext
    {
        public EntityContext() : base(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServer())
        {

        }
        
        public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int ID{get;set;}
    }
    
    
    public class Vegetable: Ingredient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        public int IDX{get{ return this.ID; } set { this.ID = value; }}
    }
}


There's no inheritance in the question. EF like all ORMs deals with application entities, not tables. Implementing an interface isn't an inheritance relation.  There's no Manager:Person relation, there are two unrelated Table classes, which is a pretty big warning sign.
If the question gets rephrased to Is it OK to use interfaces in entities the answer is It depends on the actual case. And without knowing what other interfaces are used in the application, or how IId is used beyond this code, I'd say it's not a good use.
If we want a uniform Id in code but different column names we could use the following code. EF doesn't need it though and will treat Id as a primary key by convention :
public class Tag:IId
{
    [Column("TagId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

EF itself needs no IId or IEntity interfaces. Interfaces are hard-coded while the lambdas and Expression<>s used by LINQ are far more dynamic and flexible, while still type safe. EF itself can use naming conventions to detect not just primary keys but relations as well.
EF out of the box will tread Id or TypeXYZId properties with a primitive type as primary keys. It will treat properties with names matching other entities as relations. In this example the Id columns are treated as primary keys automatically while Tags and Posts are treated as relations based on columns named PostId, TagId. In EF Core 7 and later even the bridge table PostTags will be inferred automatically :
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; } = new List<Tag>();
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}

EF would recognize Tag.TagId as a primary key too
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}

If we wanted to use Id in the entity but TagId in the table we could use
public class Tag
{
    [Column("TagId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

After that implementing IId doesn't need partial classes:
public class Tag:IId
{
    [Column("TagId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

We can avoid modifying the entities themselves too, if we use fluent configuration
